Inertia share is not working from event listener
I have to pass the menu list to all the pages. this menu list should generate dynamically, so I used the login events listener to do that, here I can able to create the menu but when I try to share the menu list using inertia::share it does not work
I need to share the menu list with all the pages, this menu should be generated once the user logs in.
below is my code.
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Session;

class LogAuthenticatedUser
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        // You can customize what you want to do here
        $menu = [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => '/'],
            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => '/about'],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => '/contact'],
            // Add more items as needed
        ];

        Inertia::share([
            'menu' => $menu
        ]);
       
    }



Are you using Inertia with Vuejs, have you tried sharing via the handleIntertiaRequests middleware

@EmekaMbah I'm using inertia with react. how do we pass these values to handleIntertiaRequests?

In menu generator
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as User;

class Menu
{
    public function generate(User $user): array
    {
        return [
            [
                'title' => 'Dashboard',
                'icon' => 'home',
                'route' => 'dashboard',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Users',
                'icon' => 'users',
                'route' => 'users',
                'can' => $user->can('viewAny', User::class),
            ],
        ];
    }
}


In event listener
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use App\Helpers\Menu;

readonly class UserEventSubscriber
{
    public function __construct(
        private Menu $menu
    ){
    }

    /**
     * Handle user login events.
     */
    public function handleUserLogin(Login $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->user;

        session()->put('menu', $this->menu->generate($user));
    }

    /**
     * Handle user logout events.
     */
    public function handleUserLogout(Logout $event): void {}

    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    public function subscribe(Dispatcher $events): array
    {
        return [
            Login::class => 'handleUserLogin',
            Logout::class => 'handleUserLogout',
        ];
    }
}


In App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Middleware;

class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The root template that's loaded on the first page visit.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup#root-template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $rootView = 'app';

    /**
     * Determines the current asset version.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/asset-versioning
     */
    public function version(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return parent::version($request);
    }

    /**
     * Define the props that are shared by default.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/shared-data
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function share(Request $request): array
    {
        $request->user()->currentTeam;

        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'menu' => session('menu', []),
        ]);
    }
}


If can't find the HandleInertiaRequests middleware then:
php artisan inertia:middleware

Then, append the HandleInertiaRequests middleware to the web middleware group in your application's bootstrap/app.php file.
use App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests;

->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->web(append: [
        HandleInertiaRequests::class,
    ]);
})


Here you are passing the static menu list in the HandleInertiaRequests, But in my case, I have to fetch the menu list from the database based on the user ID. if I use this method it will call each time to get the list, but I want to fetch the menu list once when the user logged in.

You could store it in the cache or session
